# A Numbered Variable Spawning Another Numbered Variable

Tags: java, math, numbers

So you begin with four variables.

```
Variable A = Any #;
Variable B = Any #;
Variable C = 1;
Variable D = 1;
```

Variable C & D will always equal to 1.

**Question:**

How many additions would it take for C & D to correlate with variables A & D when variable C might add itself to D count and variable D might add itself to C count.

**For Example**

```
Variable A = 4;
Variable B = 7;

Output -> 4
```

This is because of the pattern (C=1, D=1):

```
C+=D        C+=D        D+=C        D+=C         / Equations    
C=2 D=1 (1) C=3 D=1 (2) C=3 D=4 (3) C=3 D=7 (4) / Output (4 in total)
```

**How to get further results?**

Well I came up with a method were you go backwards to figure out the total additions it would take.

```
count = 0;

if(A == B)
{
   "return impossible";
}
else if (A > B)
{
    A = A - B;
    count++;
}
else if (B > A)
{
    B = B - A;
    count++;
}
```

**??? Puzzling Question ???**

This works perfectly for lower numbers, but the problem is that the program must be able to handle numbers up to the 10^50 power. All my variables are stored in BigInteger variables and I have completed 4/5 test cases. The last test case is failing due to run-time error. The test case is unknown but I have a hunch that it is 10^50. My question is if there is any way to optimize the solution to receive the number of additions faster, or perhaps another way of solving the problem with an equation? Thanks in advance!

**For further debugging beyond pseudo code above (My Code):**

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(answer("5000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "5")); //vA big number and a small number
}

public static String answer(String M, String F) 
{
    String str = testPossibilities(M, F);

    return str;
}

public static String testPossibilities(String M, String F)
{
      BigInteger nM = new BigInteger(M);
      BigInteger nF = new BigInteger(F);
      BigInteger inc = new BigInteger("1");
      BigInteger count = new BigInteger("0");

      while (BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nM) == -1 || BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nF) == -1) 
      {
          BigInteger offset = new BigInteger("" + (nM.divide(new BigInteger("2"))));

          System.out.print(nM + " " + nF + "\n"); // Print results

          if(nM.compareTo(nF) == 0 || BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nM) == 1 || BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nF) == 1) // If equal then not possible
          {
              return "impossible";
          }
          else if(nM.compareTo(nF) == 1)
          {
              if(nM.compareTo(nF.multiply(offset)) == 1)
              {
                  nM = nM.subtract(nF.multiply(offset));
                  count = count.add(nF.multiply(offset));                 
              }
              else
              {
                  nM = nM.subtract(nF);
                  count = count.add(inc);                     
              }
          }
          else if(nF.compareTo(nM) == 1)
          {
               nF = nF.subtract(nM);
               count = count.add(inc);
          }

      }

      if (BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nM) == 0 && BigInteger.valueOf(1).compareTo(nF) == 0) //If everything went ok then return the number
      {
          return "" + count;
      }

      return "impossible";

}
```

Comment: Your pseudocode isn't that helpful in explaining what you're asking here.  Can you post your real code?

Comment: What run-time error are you getting?

Comment: @Makoto I have added my code. David Wallace, eclipse will run my code forever but when I post the code to be sent to a server, the server will terminate the script if the script takes too long. So I get the error "Error(408): Request took longer than expected. Please try again." or "Time limit exceeded." Which really does not help when I know I am not stuck in an infinite loop, but it is the fact that the subtraction takes awhile.

Comment: If your input is 4 and 7, it takes 5 iterations to reach 1,1 respectively, why 4?

Comment: @Thrasher Beginning Vars C=4/D=7 -> start iterations C=4/D=3(1) C=1/D=3(2) C=1/D=2(3)  C=1/D=1(4)

Comment: If is it impossible, do you need to calculate anyway? or you could check before start going backwards?

Comment: I have verified that the unknown test case is in fact possible by running a test with only returning "impossible". Cases such as A=5000001 & B=5 will output ->1000004 which is possible but will take longer than 10 seconds to find a result.

Comment: I'm trying to get an answer by equation with no results. Have you tried a solution with mods? this could reduce the amount of time to find the result.

Comment: I have found the solution and posted the solution below. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on a faster algorithm, it took nearly a second to calculate `(5000000000000000000000000000000000000000,5)` and it's based on `mod`:

1. Keep calculations while `( A != B ) && ( A != 0 ) && ( B != 0 )`.
2. count = Divide max / min (from nF vs nM ). If it's more than 0, return that value, else return 1.
3. nM = nM mod nF.
4. nF = nF mod nM.

Then, after the iteration we could analyze the results:

1. If nF or nM reached 0, but the other number is != 1, it's impossible.
2. Else return the successful count to M and F.

### Method:

```
public static String answer( String M, String F )
{
     BigInteger nM = new BigInteger(M);
     BigInteger nF = new BigInteger(F);
     long count = 0;


     while ( !nM.equals ( nF ) && !nM.equals ( new BigInteger ( "0" ) ) && !nF.equals ( new BigInteger ( "0" ) ) ) 
     {
         BigInteger divide = (nF.max ( nM )).divide ( nF.min ( nM ) );
         count += divide.compareTo ( new BigInteger ( "0" ) ) == 1 ? divide.longValue ( ) : 1;
         BigInteger originalNM = nM;
         BigInteger originalNF = nF;
         nM = originalNM.mod ( originalNF );
         nF = originalNF.mod ( originalNM );
         System.out.println(nM + " " + nF + " " + count); // Print results
     }
     if (nM.intValue ( ) == 0 && nF.intValue ( ) != 1) return "impossible " + (count-1);
     if (nM.intValue ( ) != 1  && nF.intValue ( ) == 0) return "impossible " + (count-1); 

     return "" + (count-1);

}
```

### I/O Example:

```
Input: 
( "5000000000000000000000000000000000000000" , "5" )

Output: 
0 5 6873995514006732800
impossible 6873995514006732799

Input:
( "123123123" , "43" )

Output:
19 43 2863328
19 5 2863330
4 5 2863333
4 1 2863334
0 1 2863338
2863337

Input:
( "4" , "7" )

Output:
4 3 1
1 3 2
1 0 5
4
```

**Note:** This algo goes until 0, so the correct `count` would be `count-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to cut down the numbers.

For example, if you had a goal of A=24 and a goal of B=5 the answer would be 8.

**How? Pseudo Code**

```
count = 0;

A/B = 4; // as an integer
count += A/B; //Why? See how many times B can go into A w/ out overreaching A's value

Then 

A%B = 4; // as an integer

Now apply the subtraction method but with A being set equal to the modulus of A%B.

 A=4 B=5 // New subtraction values.

 count = 0;

 if(A == B)
 {
   "return impossible";
 }
 else if (A > B)
 {
    A = A - B;
    count++;
 }
 else if (B > A)
 {
    B = B - A;
    count++;
 }
```

**This works for large numbers as well.**

The explanation is in pseudo code because the question was how to cut down big numbers given the situation.